# How should I solve $ \int \frac{e^{2x-\frac {x^2}{4}}}{({x+4})^{8}}\, dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have tried but nothing seems to work. I need help.
$$ \int \frac{e^{2x-\frac{x^2}{4}}}{({x+4})^{8}}\, dx $$

if we get $$ t=x+4 $$ it yields:

$$  e^{-12}\int\frac{e^{4t-\frac{t^2}{4}}}{{t}^{8}}\, dt $$
Now how do we advance?

Comment: The solution is ugly and wolfram could not resolve it in terms of standard functions: [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bexp%5C%2840%29-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2CPower%5B%5C%2840%29x%2Ba%5C%2841%29%2CDivide%5BPower%5Ba%2C2%5D%2C2%5D%5D%5D%2Cx%5D)

Comment: You should always check integrals you think are difficult with a computer like this, to see if a solution even exists at all!

Comment: If it was fot $\int_0^\infty$, the results are not too bad.

Comment: Here is a [“closed form” function](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/na/NA_papers/NA2009_02.pdf) for the $\int_0^\infty$ case. See formula $1.10$.

Comment: We could do the integral if the exponent was $e^{-2x-x^4}$ or if the denominator was $(x-4)^8$ - rather than what is written here. Worth checking again the statement of the problem.

Comment: If the minus sign were a plus, then you would be able to express the indefinite integral in terms of usual functions. By the way one does not "solve" an integral.

Comment: thanks. But the expression is correct!

Comment: @FShrike Your link creates confusion for Wolfram Alpha and ends up getting the wrong input.

Comment: @TymaGaidash It worked on mine; admittedly the online wolfram alpha has been playing up recently

Answer (score 4):

*Too long for comments.*

If you are concerned by
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-x^2}}{(x+a)^b}\,dx \quad \text{with}\quad a \geq 0\quad \text{and}\quad b \geq 0$$ we have
$$I(a,b)=\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{1-b}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{b}{2};\frac{1}{2};-a^2\right)+a \Gamma
   \left(\frac{2-b}{2}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{b+1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-a^2\right)-$$
$$\frac{a^{1-b}}{1-b}\, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{2-b}{2},\frac{3-b}{2};-a^2\right)$$ where appears twice  the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function and a generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i am looking for indefinite integral.

Comment: Very, very, very little hope ! I am ready to bet.

Comment: There is hope in despair!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can we express it as some sort of *erf(x)* asking just cz I know you are good at Hypergeometric functions...... also $_1F_1 $ has to do something with $erf(x)$

Comment: Well yes @Polymath, I believe they can be expressed in terms of $erf(x)$

Comment: @JimJ there are times when there is really no hope: no hope whatsoever :-)

Comment: Have a look at my answer @Polymath, how to express in terms of Gaussian error function.

Comment: @RAHUL I appreciate your efforts but error function is defined by the upper limit of integration please check that it's not *erf(s)* By *erf* I mean $$\int_0^{\lambda}\frac{e^{2x-\frac{x^2}{4}}}{(x+4)^8}dx$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici [Here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F2/03/) are some possible simplifications for the $\,_2\text F_2$ function. How did you get the result? It [looks like](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hypergeometricpfq%28%7B1%2F2%2C1%7D%2C%7B4%2C4%2B1%2F2%7D%2Ce%29) for integer $b$ values and any $a$ value that the result is a sum of error functions

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{}^{}\frac{e^{2x-\frac{x^2}{4}}}{(x+4)^8}dx$$
After doing some efforts one can complete the square in the power of $e$ as follows,
$$e^{4}2^{-7}\int_{}^{}\frac{e^{-(u+2)^2} e^{4u}}{(u+2)^8}du$$
Now let's substitute $t=u+2 \implies dt=du$.
$$e^{3}2^{-7}\int_{}^{}\frac{e^{-(t)^2} e^{4t}}{(t)^8}du \rightarrow (1)$$
Now I will calculate the integral,
$$\int_{}^{}\frac{e^{-t^{2}} e^{4t}}{t^8}dt$$
Let,
$$ I(a)=\int_{}^{}\frac{e^{at^2} e^4t}{t^8} dt$$
Notice that,
$$ I^{(4)}(a)=\int_{}^{}\frac{e^{at^2} t^8 e^4t}{t^8}dt$$
$$ I^{(4)}(a)=\int_{}^{} e^{at^2}  e^4tdt$$
$$ I^{(4)}(a)=\int_{}^{} e^{at^2+4t} dt$$
To express this in terms of error function. Notice that,
$$ f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a(x-p)^2+k$$
Where, $p=\frac{-b}{2a}, k=ap^2+bp+c$.
This idea is analogous to conversion of cubic to a depressed one.
$$ I^{(4)}(a)=e^{k}\int_{}^{} e^{a(t-p)^2} dt $$
Put, $s=(t-p)\sqrt{a} \implies dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}ds$
$$ I^{(4)}(a)=\frac{e^k}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{}^{} e^{s^2}ds$$
$$ I^{(4)}(a)=\frac{e^k}{\sqrt{a}} erfi(s)$$
$$ I^{(4)}(a)=\frac{e^k}{\sqrt{a}} erfi((t-p)\sqrt{a})$$

Now, one should integrate on both sides $4$ times to get $I(a)$.
Evaluating $I(-1)$ and placing it in $eq.(1)$ one can evaluate the Integral in terms of error function. As the process suggests, the anti derivative in terms of error functions is complicated. The answer by @Claude Leibovici in terms of hypergeometric functions is best.

Comment: Please check @Rahul it's not erf(s) error function is defined by its upper limit

Comment: Yaa, I didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing that. Then is there any representation for $\int_{}^{}e^{s^2}ds$?

Comment: Will try to check and let you know (by *check* I mean Yes there is some thing for this $\int e^{s^2}ds$ but not sure for this sign of index if I could remember there is some function $f(x)$ in a book in the form of summation series

Comment: Well, I found that it's imaginary error function. It can also be expressed in terms of [Dawson integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function)

Comment: $$erfi(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^x e^{s^2}ds$$ 
It's uncertain if there exists any notation (f(s)) for indefinite integral

Comment: Since, $erfi(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^x e^{s^2}ds$ so  $erfi(0)=0$ and I think it's valid to write it as an indefinite integral, which takes only upper bound into account as required.

Answer (score 1):

The function
$$
f(y)=\int_a^y \frac{e^{2x-\frac{x^2}{4}}}{(x+4)^8}dx
$$
Is not defined if $a$ and $y$ are on opposite sides of $-4$. This is so because the integrand diverges at $x=4$ and the integral cannot be computed in this case. When $y$ is not too large, for example if $|y|<8$ (the number $8$ is taken since the integrand is already very small there) the integrand is essentially zero and do not contribute to the integral as can be easily seen by plugging in some numbers. For $|y|<8$ and $a>4$ we can easily get a good approximation for the integral. For $0<y<8$ we write:
$$
\frac1{(x+4)^8} =e^{-8\ln(x+4)}\approx e^{-8(\ln 4+\frac {x}{4}-\frac {x^2}{32} +\frac{x^3}{192})}
$$
Subtituting this into the integral we get:
$$
f(y)\approx \frac 1{4^8}\int_a^y e^{-\frac{x^3}{24}}dx=\frac{(24)^{ 1/3}}{3\cdot4^8} \Gamma[(\frac13,\frac{y^3}{24})-\Gamma(\frac13,\frac{a^3}{24})]
$$
where the last step was performed with the help of Wolfram Alpha and contains the incomplete Gamma functionץ
For $y$ greater than $8$ the integrand is very small and do not contribute to the integral, so we can take the integral at that range as essentially constant.

Comment: Thanks. You have made a mistake in calculating f(y).

Comment: Can you point out the error?

Comment: f(y) is obtained with your approximation as follows: $$  f(y)=...=e^(2x-0.25x^2).e^(-8(ln4+x/4-x^2/32)=4^(-8).e^(2x-0.25x^2-2x+0.25x^2)=4^(-8).e^(0)=4^(-8)  $$

Comment: Thanks - it was corrected